# What are the implications of Image.cache?

Tags: image, qt, caching, qml, qtquick2

The `Image` Qt Quick component has a `cache` property. The documentation on that property, however, is very scant. In particular, it does not say what the cache is used for, and when images are loaded from the cache.

**Can you tell me the implications of setting `Image.cache` to either true or false?**

I'm asking because I'm tempted to save a lot of memory by setting `cache: false` on all my Images.

The docs do say this:

> Images are cached and shared internally, so if several Image items have the same source, only one copy of the image will be loaded.

But does this mean that `cache: true` only has a point when several Image items have the same source? And does it mean that `cache: false` results in no gain whatsoever?

**Note:** In my tests with ~1000 images mem usage dropped from 247MB to 237MB when I disabled cache. And this app has a lot of other things in it too. So I'm happy with this win. But my questions stand.

Answer (score 1):

The difference you have is in the margin of error. QML is very careless with memory management. Make sure the behavior is consistent before you write it off as a gain.

What the doc actually says about `Image.cache` is:

> Specifies whether the image should be cached. The default value is
>   true. Setting cache to false is useful when dealing with large images,
>   to make sure that they aren't cached at the expense of small 'ui
>   element' images.

Which I assume is that the image will be kept in (presumably) GPU RAM whereas non-cached images are transferred there on demand. As far as I know, all `Images`, visible or not, will take up system RAM, which has always been odd to me, since having an image that is solely for the purpose of visualizing on a GPU backend can actually omit the copy in RAM and only keep the image in VRAM.

The doc entry you quote looks like it concerns the scenegraph, that caching is implicit, which only makes sense, because there is no reason storing the same data twice, it will refcount each image url so that if it is used multiple times it will resolve to the same single packet of data. `Image.cache` has nothing to do with that cache.

At any rate, I'd say the only viable solution to make sizable gains is to do lazy loading. Using vectors won't save you much, since the images are internally cached rasterized. Using more compressed images will reduce the binary size, but they are still cached decoded in memory.

If your images are stuff like grayscale icon stencils, they render tremendously well to signed distance field representation. In my project I managed to reduce 83 MB worth of such icons to 1.25 MB of SDFs with no loss of quality, in fact with the SDFs I was able to enlarge the GUI even more without getting jagged edges. And the shader to render an SDF into a raster of the appropriate size is only a tad more complex than a flat color shader, so performance differences are negligible, but since this happens on the fly I also get the same amount of memory saved from both RAM and VRAM.